# Do the BA A388 planes have the same folding headrest as KLM?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft, british-airways

I took a KLM economy flight long distance (Johannesburg to London) in 2022 that had headrests with wings that folded forward for neck support to make for a very comfortable night's sleep (a revelation as airplane sleep goes).

I'm soon to be flying the same route with BA, on an A388. I wonder if anyone can tell me if the BA A388 economy headrests are likely to be the same?

Comment: [Seatguru](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/British_Airways/British_Airways_Airbus_A380_new.php?flightno=56&date=) has some photos of the seats.. check them out..

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what headrests folding upwards could be. Do you have picture or something that explains it?

Comment: @jcaron I think the OP is asking about a seat where the headrest portion moves _up and down_ a little. [This photo](https://i0.wp.com/insideflyer.nl/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Review-KLM-Economy-Comfort-Boeing-787-9-Dreamliner-Schiphol-Amsterdam-Airport-Calgary-Airport-Canada-Netherlands-Nederland-22.jpeg?resize=1024%2C768&ssl=1) from KLM shows a KLM seat, where the headrest portion, now in its lowest position, can be moved up several inches if the passenger wishes.

Comment: I've seen seats that have 'wings' on the side that you can bend forwards. That's what I thought the OP was asking about.

Comment: @mkennedy is correct. I have edited the question to make this clearer

Comment: KLM doesn't operate the A388, so their seats won't be the same as those on a BA A388 as seats differ between aircraft models, even within a single carrier's fleet

Comment: The KLM seats I mention above have the same adjustable "wings."

Answer (score 4):

The answer was that no, the BA A388 did not have the adjustable headrest wings that I was looking for. The headrest had wings that tilted forwards but were fixed permanently at an angle that made my head continuously slide forwards and off the headrest.